# Unmountable System Partition Issue (TWRP)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, twrp, partitions, micromax

I'm currently in the throes of a complex issue with my Android device (Phone Model: [Micromax Canvas Juice 2], Recovery: TWRP 3.0). I've exhausted several troubleshooting steps, and here's a detailed breakdown:

1. **Root Problem:**

   - The system partition is unmountable, leading to a persistent "System not mounted" error during recovery attempts.
2. **Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

   - Utilized TWRP terminal to create a new system partition, aiming to restore from a comprehensive backup stored on an SD card.
   - Faced challenges with the manual partition creation, including uncertainty about the consequences of deleting the unmountable system partition.
3. **Specific Questions and Concerns:**

   - What are the potential risks and consequences of deleting the unmountable system partition?
   - Seeking detailed guidance on whether to proceed with deletion or opt for creating a new partition manually.
4. **Additional Context:**

   - The device is an older model running Android 5, and it's been a formidable challenge due to the lack of manufacturer support.
5. **Request for Expert Advice:**

   - If anyone has navigated a similar issue with TWRP and Android partitions, your insights would be invaluable.
   - Detailed, step-by-step instructions or any creative solutions are highly appreciated.

---

Overall overview. The phone is stuck in a bootloop. Created TWRP backup of all partitions. Downloaded custom ROM, and followed instructions to wipe "system, Dalvik cache, cache, and data." Couldn't flash ROM due to the "System is not mounted (invalid argument)" error. Manual attempts to mount, decrypt, repair the file system, and change the system file type were unsuccessful. Considering manual deletion of system partition file in TWRP file manager or creating a new system partition using TWRP terminal.